# drawing gaussian random variables using scipy erfinv

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, scientific-computing

I would like to draw *npts* random variables distributed as a gaussian with mean *mu* and dispersion *sigma*. I know how to do this in Numpy:

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=npts)
print(np.std(x), np.mean(x))
0.1998, 0.3997
```

This should also be possible to do using scipy.special.erfinv via inverse transforms, beginning from a uniform distribution:

```
u = np.random.uniform(0, 1, npts)
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the scaling correct. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: What means *npts*? Do i understand correctly, that you just want samples of the parameterized normal dist? If so, why not using the numpy approach?

Comment: My use case requires starting from *u*.

Comment: npts is just the number of times to draw from the distribution

Comment: *"My use case requires starting from u."* Could you explain a bit more about your motivation?

Comment: Sure, ali_m. I will be using the percentile of a x, a physical quantity of interest in my model, as the array u. The gaussian variable is the distribution of the modeled quantity y. In this way, x and y are in monotonic correspondence, and y is a gaussian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
mean = 100
sigma = 7
x = mean + 2**0.5 * sigma * erfinv(np.random.uniform(size=10**5) * 2 - 1)
x.mean(), x.std()
Out: (99.965915366042381, 7.0062395839075107)
```

[image]

The conversion from erf to normal distribution is from [John D. Cook's blog](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/03/15/error-function-and-the-normal-distribution/).

Comment: Perfect answer: exactly what I needed, and very fast even for large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would probably be an own implementation of highly-optimized gaussian-samplers like:

- [polar-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method)
- [ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm)
- [box-muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)

But here is something simple (which i saw a long time ago [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyDOE/randomized.html)). This will be less efficient than the approaches above (as it's using the quantile function / percent point function which has no closed-form representation for the normal-distribution and will be approximated):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.distributions import norm

uniform_samples = np.random.rand(100000)
gaussian_samples = norm(loc=0, scale=1).ppf(uniform_samples)
```

Comment: Thanks sascha. This is an interesting solution, but a little less clear than the transparent erfinv method, and ~3x slower for very large arrays.

Comment: @aph In my opinion this is much clearer. It's just inverse-transform sampling with  the ppf-function (using the distribution you want to sample from). I also think, that if erfinv can do this with a linear-transformation, it's inverse-function is also not representable in closed-form and needs approximation too (internally). One of the above algorithms, implemented in a few lines should be 100x faster if done right (there is a reason they are used by all fast rng-libs). But i accept, that ayhan answers your question more precise as you wanted some erfinv-based method. :-)

Comment: Ok sascha, I will check the links you suggested and try to adapt them before checking the accepted answer. I only prefer the erfinv-based answer because the connection to inverse transformation sampling is plain and explicit directly at the syntax level.

Comment: I'm cool with accepting ayhan's answer. And i think, you should go first with one of these two simple approaches. Only implement one of the above (or grab some numpy/scipy internals) if speed is too slow for you.